# How to Count a specific status which is mentioned in a cell in Google sheets

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I am new to Excel, I have a Question mentioned in image

I have  multiple Status across same ID  and I want to identify that if Status corresponding to that ID is `Yes` at least once I want to mark Final Status as `Yes`.

If Status is not `Yes` at least once then It should be counted as `No`, how can I do that in Google sheets

***Image:***
[image]

Comment: Is your question about Excel or GS?

Answer (score 1):

Try `Countifs()`. This will work both on `Excel` and `google-sheets`.

```
=IF(COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$14,D2,$B$2:$B$14,"Yes")>0,"Yes","No")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In Google Sheets, you could use:

```
=query({A:B},"select Col1,Max(Col2) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 order by Max(Col2) desc label Max(Col2) 'Final Status' ",1)
```

[image]